# Python Pandas - Calculate Min, Max, and Mean with a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I'm trying to create a function called sales_recap to calculate the minimum, maximum, and average value of a sale.

```
def sales_recap(sales)
```

for example, if I have a dataframe as an input like this :

```
sales = pd.DataFrame({
    'Type':['Electronics', 'Electronics', 'Electronics', 'Home_Decor', 'Home_Decor', 'Kids', 'Kids, 'Kids],
    'Price':[100,100,70,60,80,50,50,50]})
```

And if I run the function

```
sales_recap(sales)
```

it should give a result like this

```
recap = pd.DataFrame({
    'Type':['Electronics', 'Home_Decor','Kids'],
    'Min_Price':[70,60,50],
    'Average':[90,70,50],
    'Max_Price':[100,80,50]
})
```

I'm new to python and I still don't have the ideas how to do this with a function so that I can use the function with another inputs. Thank You! :)

Comment: Hi, try with `sales.describe()`...  you will get a summary statistics of your data, [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)

Comment: @cards `describe()` does not give the expected output

Comment: I know... it was just a comment, not an answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_agg`:

```
>>> sales.groupby('Type').agg(Min_Price=('Price', 'min'),
                              Average=('Price', 'mean'),
                              Max_Price=('Price', 'max')).reset_index()

          Type  Min_Price  Average  Max_Price
0  Electronics         70     90.0        100
1   Home_Decor         60     70.0         80
2         Kids         50     50.0         50
```